Rich man hires ex convict to spy on his wife
A rich man hires an ex-convict (prisoner, murderer) to spy on his blonde wife because he suspects she's cheating on him. As time goes by the ex-convict and the wife fall in love. The husband almost caught them together because the ex-convict's dog-tags were left on the bed after making love. 
They form a plot to rob the husband and run away, but the husband comes back early from a business trip and after a quarrel he kills his wife.  She is found in a bathtub laying in blood. The ex-convict, after finding out what happened, kills (or tries to kill — can't recall) the husband.
During the movie there are short scenes of a woman laying in bed (or bathtub) and blood transfusion. As the movie unravels it turns out that the wife collected her blood in order to fake her own murder to get rid of her husband and the ex-convict: husband killed by the ex-con and the ex-con in prison. She ran away with her true lover, the gardener. They fly away and the movie ends.
I can't remember the actors well, but I think that the rich husband resembled Alec Baldwin, Michael Madsen, or Steven Seagal and the ex-con resembled William H. Macy or David Caruso.
I think I watched it between 2008 and 2010.

When did you watch this?

I think between 2008-2010 but I am not sure. It should be good known movie. I think that name of the movie is short like one word but not sure either

is the Movie The Illusionist (2006) if yes then I'll add it as an answer.

Its not that movie.Any other ideas
Thanks

It is cold play 2008 from other movie forum if anyone stumbles upon

@ChristianRau you're right, I was too quick on commenting. I'll just remove my comment ;)

Is it Cold Play? It's a 2008 movie. Here's the blurb from the IMDB page:

A multi millionaire suspects his wife of having an affair. He hires a private eye to tail her but they form a romantic alliance of their own and plot to steal the husband's 20 million dollar Imperial Egg.

Here's another synopsis from Rotten Tomatoes:

An obsessive millionaire who suspects that his wife is having an affair finds that no one can be trusted after hiring a shady private detective to track her every move in this thriller from co-directors Geno Andrews and D. David Morin. Winston Thorpe (Morin) doesn't trust his wife Indigo (Vanessa Branch), and in order to gather the evidence needed to get her out of his life he hires scheming Scottish private investigator Angus Stuart. Little did Thorpe suspect that Indigo and Angus would form an alliance designed to rob him of his fortune, but after Angus agrees to help make Indigo "disappear" the pair soon starts to get sloppy with their plan. Now, as Thorpe discovers the damning evidence that links Indigo and Angus together, the vengeful husband quickly goes to work dreaming up a deadly scheme of his own.

Here's the trailer on YouTube
